# A non flat $R$-module $M$ with $\operatorname{Tor}_{n}^R(k,M)=0$ for all $n\ge 1$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I want to find a non-flat $R$-module $M$ with $\operatorname{Tor}_{n}^R(k,M)=0 \,\, \forall n\ge 1$, where $R=k[x,y]/(xy)$ and $k$ is field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1081315/121097) to your previous question I have constructed a free resolution of $k$ as an $R$-module
$$\cdots\longrightarrow R^2\stackrel{v}\longrightarrow R^2\stackrel{u}\longrightarrow R^2\stackrel{v}\longrightarrow R^2\stackrel{u}\longrightarrow R^2\stackrel{f}\longrightarrow R\longrightarrow 0$$ where $f(r_1,r_2)=r_1x+r_2y$, $u(a_1,a_2)=(a_1y,a_2x)$, and $v(b_1,b_2)=(b_1x,b_2y)$.

Now consider $M=R/(x,y-1)$. Tensoring the above resolution by $M$ we get $$\cdots\longrightarrow M^2\stackrel{\bar v}\longrightarrow M^2\stackrel{\bar u}\longrightarrow M^2\stackrel{\bar v}\longrightarrow M^2\stackrel{\bar u}\longrightarrow M^2\stackrel{\bar f}\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow 0$$ where $\bar f(r_1,r_2)=r_2$, $\bar u(a_1,a_2)=(a_1,0)$, and $\bar v(b_1,b_2)=(0,b_2)$.

Comment: This is a very nice example. Is this your own example or does this exist in some literature?

Comment: @Youngsu I didn't find it somewhere else. (Actually I've started from $\operatorname{Tor}_1$ thinking how to chose an ideal $I$ such that $\operatorname{Tor}_1(R/m,R/I)=0$. Since this is isomorphic to $(m\cap I)/mI$ I've thought that the best candidate is another maximal ideal since then they are comaximal and the intersection equals the product.)

Comment: In fact i think that all the above maps that you have written are multiplied by y

Comment: @noether23 $y=1$ in $R/(x,y-1)$.

Comment: ok. you are right. Thank you