# Computing Tor for quotient module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

> Let $B= \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ and consider the module $M=B/(x,y)$. How can I use a free resolution of $M$ in to compute $\text{Tor}^{B}_i(M,M)$.

This is an exercise from my book, but the book contains no examples so I am not really sure how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have a free resolution for $M$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  I have not found a free resolution for $M$, I have tried some compuations but did not manage.

Comment: There is a canonical free resolution obtained by consider $M_0$ to be the free module over M, and $M_1$ to be the free module over the kernel elements of the canonical $M_0$ to $M$.

Comment: @정준환 can this resolution also be used to compute tor? Would you post an answer in that case?

Comment: I really think that the best thing would be for you to construct a free resolution yourself... Can you think of a free module $F$ and a surjective map $F\to M$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  yes I can, $B$ itself. The kernel of this map would be the ideal $(x,y)$ but how can I find another free module such that its image equals this kernel?

Comment: How about $B^2$?

Comment: Do you know some set of generators for that kernel?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez i guess the map $B \oplus B \to B$ given by componentwise multiplication with $(x,y)$ would work. The kernel of this map would in turn be the set $(Px,Py)$ and so the next map would be $B \to B \oplus B$ with multplication by $(x,y)$. The kernel of this map is trivial since the polynomial ring is an integral domain. Hence the resolution is constructed. Is this correct?

Comment: What is $P{}{}$?

Comment: In your question there is a ring $B$, a ring $A$ and none of them is a polynomial ring... You should probably decide what ring you are working with!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  yes you are right, I am just tired so I used the wrong words, I think I got it though.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  I will update the question with an answer tomorrow, is it ok to ask for your opinion by then?

Comment: I'd suggest to edit the question now so that it makes sense! You can add your answer later, of course.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez what in the question should I edit? This is precisly the question.

Comment: In the question there is an $A$ and a $B$...

Comment: @conrad Actually the resolution is infinite and looks like: $\cdots\to B^2\to B^2\to B^2\to B\to 0$, where the maps $B^2\to B^2$ are given by a $2\times 2$ matrix having $(x,y)$ and $(y,-x)$ as its rows. This shows that $\mathrm{Tor}_i(M,M)=M^2$ for $i\ge 1$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081299/projective-resolution-of-k-over-r-kx-y-xy

Comment: @user26857  Thank you for your help! But how do you compute tor as $M^2$?

Comment: @conrad When tensor by $M$ the matrix becomes zero since its entries are in the ideal $(x,y)$. In fact, you get $\cdots\to M^2\to M^2\to M^2\to M\to 0$ and all differentials from $M^2$ to the left are zero.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you. I am not sure about the resolution though, for $B^2 \ to B^2 \to B^2$ i get that the image is included in the kernel this is straightforward to check. But how can i see that the kernel is included in the image?